# ElasticSearch - Disable auto creation of index UNLESS there is a template

Tags: elasticsearch

So I know I can disable auto creation completely, and I know I can set wildcard-expressions to enable/disable specific indices auto creations. But I want to enable auto creation of an index if there is a template matched to it.

So imagine the scenario where you have a service A that creates the index template, and service B that index data to it.

In this case service B should not be allowed to index data until service A has created a template for the indices.

This is to avoid a race condition where service B could index data (and create a default index) before service A was done with the template.

Is there any setting that allows me to do this?

Comment: Service B could ask ES if the template exists before attempting to index - that way you could implement fall-off and a retry strategy as well. `HEAD _template/<template_name>`

Comment: Yes that is a backup solution, but I would rather not have to make another network call (even if I can cache it) for each index request.